# What is the best practice to show or hide an image based upon a dataset field boolean?

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am doing an SSRS report copy of a form for a printout. The form has radio buttons and checkboxes, which SSRS does not have. So I imported 4 images of these controls marked on and off.

I have 2 datasets, and when I go to reference a dataset, it is forcing me to use this format.
Visibility > Show or hide based on an expression > =Sum(Fields!Q1.Value, "myDataset2")
The possible values are 1, 0, null.

Must I always refer to my dataset with an aggregate function (first, sum, etc.), or is there a way to tag my image to only be referring to this dataset?

Secondly, I need to wrap this into an IIF to determine correctly when to show or hide this image.

I plan to have the 2 images on top of each other and only show the one that correctly correlates to the saved values.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a dynamic image instead of using the invisiblity property.
=iif(sum(Fields!Q1.Value, "myDataset2")=1,"RadioTrue","RadioFalse")

Comment: That's a better way to do it anyway. Overlapping items is not supported by all renderers so you may have got unexpected results.